# Realm: Result<T>[index] not properly working

Tags: swift, realm

I query for a Result of 1000 contacts, sorted by lastname. Then I create random indices and query for the objects. But instead of random contacts I get the first n contacts... Why can objects in a sorted Result be addressed by an index if this is not properly working?

```
if let contacts = ContactsProvider.sharedInstance.loadContactsWithReload(){

    if(contacts.count <= 1){
        return nil;
    }

    if(contacts.count <= 10){
        random10Group.contacts.appendContentsOf(contacts)
    }
    else{
        var randomIndices = [Int]()
        while randomIndices.count < 10{

            let random = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(contacts.count)))
            if(!randomIndices.contains(random)){
                randomIndices.append(random)
                print(random)
            }
        }

        let contactList = List<Contact>()

        for var index = 0; index < randomIndices.count; index++ {
            let contact = contacts[index]
            contactList.append(contact)
            print(contact.fullName())
        }

        random10Group.contacts = contactList

        return random10Group
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In

```
let contactList = List<Contact>()
for var index = 0; index < randomIndices.count; index++ {
    let contact = contacts[index]
    contactList.append(contact)
}
```

`index` runs from `0` to `randomIndices.count - 1`, and that's why
you get the first contacts.

You probably meant

```
let contactList = List<Contact>()
for index in randomIndices {
    let contact = contacts[index]
    contactList.append(contact)
}
```

so that `index` runs over the *elements* of the random array.

Note that the loop can be simplified to

```
let contactList = randomIndices.map { contacts[$0] }
```